# Get unique rows from one of tables in INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

Is there any workaround to get unique rows which are in `zc_orders` table? I only need comments field from `zc_zc_orders_status_history` (which have duplicate rows). This is my query:

```
SELECT
zc_orders.orders_id,
zc_orders_status_history.comments,
zc_orders_status_history.orders_status_id,
zc_customers.customers_email_address,
zc_customers.customers_telephone,
zc_customers.customers_firstname,
zc_customers.customers_lastname,
zc_orders_status_history.date_added,
zc_orders.date_purchased
FROM
zc_customers
INNER JOIN zc_orders ON zc_orders.customers_id = zc_customers.customers_id
INNER JOIN zc_orders_status_history ON 
zc_orders_status_history.orders_id = zc_orders.orders_id
where zc_orders_status_history.orders_status_id = 8
ORDER BY zc_orders_status_history.date_added DESC
```

Comment: Can you just use a `SELECT DISTINCT`? What do you consider "Unique" for an order row? Unique Order Id?

Comment: Could you simplify the query to illustrate your problem in a minimal way? in addition, the table definitions could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
zc_orders_status_history.comments,
FROM
zc_customers
INNER JOIN zc_orders ON zc_orders.customers_id = zc_customers.customers_id
INNER JOIN zc_orders_status_history ON 
zc_orders_status_history.orders_id = zc_orders.orders_id
where zc_orders_status_history.orders_status_id = 8
ORDER BY zc_orders_status_history.date_added DESC
```